# How to use a particular gnome-terminal profile like (base-16-default-dark) every time I start a new terminal?

Tags: gnome-terminal, colors, gconf, gnome-color-manager

I would like to use Base-16-default-dark [base16 color scheme](https://github.com/chriskempson/base16) profile for my newly start terminals. Right now every time i open a new terminal it get loaded with default color scheme and i have to change the color scheme manually from gui (edit|profile preferences|general -> profile name [Base 16 Default Dark]) [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOxZ1.png)

[image: screenshot]

Below is the output for `ls` command

```
ls -l .gconf/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default
```

> total 4 -rw------- 1 vikrant vikrant 1869 Feb 23 11:47 %gconf.xml

Here is the content of my %gconf

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gconf>
    <entry name="use_custom_command" mtime="1456204966" type="bool" value="false"/>
    <entry name="login_shell" mtime="1456204953" type="bool" value="false"/>
    <entry name="allow_bold" mtime="1456203718" type="bool" value="false"/>
    <entry name="background_darkness" mtime="1456203718" type="float" value="0.61588001251220703"/>
    <entry name="use_theme_colors" mtime="1456204936" type="bool" value="false"/>
    <entry name="scrollback_unlimited" mtime="1456203718" type="bool" value="true"/>
    <entry name="scroll_background" mtime="1452540680" type="bool" value="true"/>
    <entry name="background_type" mtime="1452551801" type="string">
        <stringvalue>solid</stringvalue>
    </entry>
    <entry name="cursor_shape" mtime="1456203718" type="string">
        <stringvalue>ibeam</stringvalue>
    </entry>
    <entry name="font" mtime="1456203718" type="string">
        <stringvalue>Consolas 15</stringvalue>
    </entry>
    <entry name="use_system_font" mtime="1456203718" type="bool" value="false"/>
    <entry name="palette" mtime="1456208226" type="string">
        <stringvalue>#000000000000:#CCCC00000000:#4E4E9A9A0606:#C4C4A0A00000:#34346565A4A4:#757550507B7B:#060698209A9A:#D3D3D7D7CFCF:#555557575353:#EFEF29292929:#8A8AE2E23434:#FCFCE9E94F4F:#72729F9FCFCF:#ADAD7F7FA8A8:#3434E2E2E2E2:#EEEEEEEEECEC</stringvalue>
    </entry>
    <entry name="alternate_screen_scroll" mtime="1456203718" type="bool" value="true"/>
    <entry name="background_color" mtime="1456208209" type="string">
        <stringvalue>#000000000000</stringvalue>
    </entry>
    <entry name="visible_name" mtime="1456204474" type="string">
        <stringvalue>Default</stringvalue>
    </entry>
    <entry name="bold_color" mtime="1456203718" type="string">
        <stringvalue>#000000000000</stringvalue>
    </entry>
    <entry name="foreground_color" mtime="1456208209" type="string">
        <stringvalue>#AAAAAAAAAAAA</stringvalue>
    </entry>
</gconf>
```

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for. In `gnome-terminal`, it is in settings (gui), while from command line, you can edit the launcher to run `--window-with-profile=<profile>`. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: No I don't want that, I want if I start a brand new terminal it should come up with my custom color scheme (which I installed from base16 <https://github.com/chriskempson/base16> website ) rather than default one. I have rephrased my question, may be now it will help you to guess what am I looking for.

Comment: So if you set the new color scheme in your profile and then quit all terminals and open a new one, it will still use the old color scheme? If so, please show the output of "ls -l .gconf/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default" and the contents of the %gconf.xml file in that directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the global menubar's Edit -> Preferences, and choose the Profiles tab. Here you'll find the entry "Profile used when launching a new terminal".

Comment: In ubuntu this option is under Edit | profiles . Thank you so much  egmont .

Comment: I'm also on Ubuntu, but probably on a newer version, since the settings were moved from gconf to dconf/gsettings a while ago. Apparently the menu entry was also renamed. This really doesn't matter :)